# Fingering violin double-stopping in counterpoint

Tags: fingering, mozart

Can anybody give me a fingering for the double stopping in the Violin part for the Adagio movt of the Mozart Duo K423, bars 19 to 23?

[image: Mozart Duo K423, Adagio]
[IMSLP link](http://petrucci.mus.auth.gr/imglnks/usimg/0/09/IMSLP312344-PMLP54153-mozart_string_duo_-_Violin.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try starting in 3rd position and then crawling back to 1st position.

[image: mozart fingering]